# Question about math symbol $\bigsqcup$

Tags: notation

Can someone tell me what this symbol means?

$\bigsqcup$

Comment: It would be *extremely* helpful if you tell us where you saw it. This is like asking what does the symbol $\partial$ means. It may have different meanings in different contexts.

Comment: It's usually some generalization or specialization of the "union" sign, but it does greatly depend on context.

Comment: My default interpretation is of disjoint union, thought it's also similar to the symbol often used coproducts.

Comment: [Search results for `\bigsqcup` on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Cbigsqcup).

Comment: @Andrew: disjoint union is a coproduct. I'd say it is almost certainly some coproduct. In what category, it would depend on the context.

Comment: I simply meant that, though $\amalg$ seems to be the most common notation for general coproducts (not necessarily of sets), $\bigsqcup$ might have been used instead.

Comment: I think it tells you where to put the staple.

Comment: $\bigsqcup A$ is also used to denote (if existent) the smallest upper bound of a given subset $A \subseteq X$ of a partial ordering $(X, \le)$, but now that I think of it, this may also be viewed as a coproduct... Sorry.

Answer (score 11):

It is the disjoint union symbol- it is most commonly used informally to denote situations where you take the union of two disjoint sets. The actual definition though is more of a tagged union- intuitively, you index the sets to be unioned by some set $I$, and then the result is the collection of all the elements of each set, along with a "tag" that says which set it came from.

In your case, formally you have sets $A$ and $B$- let's re-label these $A_1$ and $A_2$. The disjoint union is $A_1 \bigsqcup A_2 =\{ (a,1) \vert a\in A_1\} \cup \{ (a,2) \vert a\in A_2\}$. So if they have some element $a$ in common, you end up with both $(a,1)$ and $(a,2)$ in your disjoint union. In the case that they have no common elements, the result is the same as the standard union.

Answer (score 1):

$A\bigsqcup B$  means that the sets are a  "disjoint" union

Comment: Does this mean $A\cap B=\emptyset$?

Comment: @Khromonkey : No, not always. See Devlin Mallory's response above.

Comment: @Khromonkey Yes